# Converting double value in spark sql

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, oracle11g, double, precision

I have a requirement in which I need to convert string to double in such a way using Spark SQL:

```
12.56 - 12.56
15.40 - 15.40
12 - 12
0 - 0
```

We do not need to round, only that whenever there is a whole number it converts like :

12 - 12.0 in double which is not expected. Can we use some other function?

Comment: No, using opensource spark

Comment: I believe it is not possible.. by default double data type will add decimals.

Comment: Please provide a sample of the desired output.